# Weka decision tree is very cluttered no options to organise it?

Tags: weka, decision-tree

Hi i am in weka trying to produce a decsion tree for the data but all i get it this
My only options that do anything are if i right click and click auto scale but then its very spread out and mostly unreadable

Searching online it states you can zoom out but zooming out on my mouse does nothing and theres no other option for it

Any help would be appreicated

Comment: What algorithm did you use?

Answer (score 0):

If you were using [J48](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/trees/J48.html), then you can use the general `-g` option on the command-line to output the graph in [Graphviz](http://graphviz.org/) [dot notation](http://graphviz.org/doc/info/lang.html) to stdout. That graph notation can then be turned into other outputs (e.g., PDF or PNG).

When using the Weka Explorer, you could try installing the [graphviz-treevisualize](https://github.com/fracpete/graphviz-treevisualize-weka-package) package (requires Graphviz to be installed, of course). With that you can display, save or export the graph.